# How do I generate sound using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fft, signal-analysis

I want to generate and play sound for tones with frequency 100 Hz and 200 Hz for 10 sec and 5 sec respectively using MATLAB with sampling frequency equal to 20500 Hz.

Also I want to plot their frequency spectrum. Is it possible to do this using MATLAB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like that should do. Please keep in mind that this code can be further improved by windowing your signal, using decibel scale for spectrum, taking only first half of a spectrum, etc. This is all cosmetic stuff and you can do it on your own (or maybe I will edit this answer at some point).

```
%% Time domain parameters
fs = 20500;    % Sampling frequency
dt = 1/fs;     % Time resolution
T = 10;        % Signal duration
t = 0:dt:T-dt; % Total duration
N = length(t); % Number of time samples

%% Signal generation
f0_1 = 100; % fundamental frequency of first sinusoid
f0_2 = 200; % fundamental frequency of second sinusoid
x1 = sin(2*pi*f0_1*t); % first sinusoid
x2 = sin(2*pi*f0_2*t); % second sinusoid

% We want 200 Hz signal to last for half of a time, therefore zero-out
% second half - use the logical indexing of time variable
x2(t>5)=0;

% Now add two signals
x = x1+x2;

% Calculate spectrum
X = abs(fft(x))/N;
% Prepare frequency axis
freqs = (0:N-1).*(fs/N);

%% Plotting time and frequency domain
% Time domain signal plot
subplot(211)
plot(t, x)
grid on
xlabel('Time [s]')
ylabel('Amplitude')
title('Time domain signal')

% Spectrum plot
subplot(212)
plot(freqs, X)
grid on
xlim([0 max(freqs)])
xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
ylabel('Amplitude')
title('Spectrum')

%% Playing back signal
% Normalize the audio:
x = 0.99*x/max(abs(x));

% For MATLAB R2014a use audioplayer
player = audioplayer(x, fs);
play(player)

% For older versions use wavplay
% wavplay(x, fs);
```

And apart from playing back it will also produce:

[image]

Comment: Why is the amplitude of 100Hz is bigger the 200Hz, is it affect by the duration (5s and 10s)?

Comment: @rubievozĐỗAnhTú Please read the question once again carefully and notice the durations of signals. One of them is switched off after 5 seconds.