# How do I generate sound using Python3?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, python, sound

I am totally a newbie in signal processing. I want to generate and play sound for frequencies (1/3 octave band center frequency) 125 Hz, 250 Hz and 500 Hz respectively, each for 30 seconds and with sampling frequency of 26.5 kHz.

I came across [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16845/how-do-i-generate-sound-using-matlab) relevant question, however, I would like to generate sound (and plot frequency spectrum) using Python3. Does someone care to help or suggest on how to do this?

Comment: what version of python3 (python33, python37??) Pyaudio for me is nice to play audios

Comment: I want to generate sound using Python3.7 or higher (Py3.8 in my case). Yup, Google told me about Pyaudio but couldn't really find a working solution. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ok i'm in a good mood today lol

Comment: That's great you are in good mood today when folks out there are getting crazy over stupid viruses :/ Thank you so much for the help :) I will give a try to your code, and post another big THANKS here soon =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is it ... install `pyaudo` to play the generated sine signal, install `numpy` to help you with arrays and math, install `matplotlib` to plot ...

I wrote this code quickly just to show how to do... some steps are commented in the code, this will play one generated signal in the choose frequency, concatenate all vectors signals and play using `pyaudio` at the end im generating the `FFT` that show the frequencies in the generated signal...

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from struct import pack
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Fs = 26500
freq1 = 125
freq2 = 250
freq3 = 500
seconds=3
nsamples = Fs*seconds
signal1 = np.arange(nsamples)
signal2 = np.arange(nsamples)
signal3 = np.arange(nsamples)
signal1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq1 * signal1 / Fs)
signal2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq2 * signal2 / Fs)
signal3 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq3 * signal3 / Fs)

#join all signals Im not crossfading and
#I'm not worrying about the continuity of the phases
sout=np.concatenate((signal1, signal2, signal3), axis=None)


# Initialize PyAudio
pyaud = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Open input stream, 32-bit mono at 26500 Hz
stream = pyaud.open(format =  pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels = 1,
                rate = Fs,
                output = True)


#play all vector, maybe can be nice if you put it in one loop
out = pack("%df"%len(sout), *(sout))
stream.write(out)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

pyaud.terminate()


#start plot Frequencies (FFT)

wsignal=sout*np.hamming(len(sout)); 
Fourier=abs(np.fft.rfft(wsignal))


NyquistTeorema = (Fs / 2)

MinFrequencia=NyquistTeorema / (len(sout) / 2);

Frequencies=np.linspace(MinFrequencia, NyquistTeorema, num=(len(sout) / 2))

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Fourier')
plt.plot(Frequencies,Fourier[0:len(Frequencies)])


plt.figure(2)
plt.title('Fourier Zoom')
plt.plot(Frequencies[0:5000],Fourier[0:5000])



plt.show()
```

The final plot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! It worked for me! :) Have a good day, and mood ;)